# Classical ring of quotients

Tags: ring-theory

Let $R$ be a ring and let $Q$ be the classical ring of right quotients of $R$. Definitely any nilpotent element in $R$ is nilpotent in $Q$. But I am trying to know what types of elements are nilpotent in $Q$. If $x=ab^{-1}\in Q$, where $a,b\in R$ and $b$ is a regular element, is nilpotent in $Q$ then can we say that $a$ is nilpotent in $R$? Please help.

Comment: It sounds like you are implicitly assuming $R$ is a right Ore ring?

Comment: @rschwieb: Yes I have assumed that $R$ is a right Ore ring.

Answer (score 1):

You can find some useful information in the book (unfortunately, in Russian)

V.A.Andrunakievich and Yu.M.Ryabukhin, *Radicals of Algebras and Structural Theory*, Nauka, Moscow (1979)

in $\S 4.3$ "Left algebras of quotients of semiprime algebras'' (here the authors mean algebras over commutative rings).

An example of their results:

**Theorem 1.** Let $R$ be an algebra without nilpotent elements. Then its left algebra of quotients has no nilpotent elements iff
$$\forall \,x,y\in R \ (Rx\cap Ry =0\Leftrightarrow xy=0).$$

Comment: @rschwieb: Of course, thank you. I corrected the answer.

Comment: Cool. A question: the theorem statement doesn't mention anything about assuming something like the right Ore conditions. Are they really working with the classical ring of quotients? Or what notion are they using if not?

Comment: @rschwieb: They define algebras of quotients by the injective hull (as in J.Lambek, "Lectures on Rings and Modules").

Comment: Ah, ok, so the so-called "maximal left ring of quotients" $Q_{max}^\ell(R)$. Thanks for the info!